# C# DataGridView detecting select all button

Tags: c#, .net

I'm developing a C# Windows Form program and I've implemented a DataGridView on it. Now, after setting the data source, when I click the top left button on the datagridview, it selects all rows, just like Microsoft Excel. However, I dynamically hide and show rows on it, and after clicking that button I realized that it also selects **the invisible ones.** I don't want to implement "SelectionChanged" event because I constantly select some rows and normally I can't select the invisible ones. Only this button selects it. I'm looking for an event like this:

```
datagridView1_SelectAllClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // do stuff
}
```

Something like this will also work since I don't have to check all selections:

```
dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(dataGridView1.IsSelectAllCells())
     {
          // do stuff
     }
}
```

If I have to, I will add the event to deselect the invisible rows, but I prefer some solution like the first one. Any advices? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I'm checking "dataGridView1.SelectedRows" property on button clicks only, not after the selection was made. So, some function that I can implement to button click events will also solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx) class provides the [AreAllCellsSelected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.areallcellsselected(v=vs.110).aspx) methode:

> Returns a value indicating whether all the DataGridView cells are currently selected. ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.areallcellsselected(v=vs.110).aspx))

With that we can get a solution like your second one:

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView view = sender as DataGridView; 

    if (view.AreAllCellsSelected(true))
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in view.Rows)
        {
            //deselect all invisible rows
            if (!row.Visible)
                row.Selected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this works fine, I really don't want to implement the event because I don't have to check other selections since they are already invisible. This event catches all selection types: column, row and cell-specific. It will just fire for nothing except the select-all button. If there is more efficient way, I'd like to use it instead of this one, because I think this method will iterate through all cells with a loop which will be inefficient in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it finally, the solution was simpler than I expected.

```
private void RemoveInvisibleSelection()
{
     if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
             if (!dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Visible)
                 dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i--].Selected = false; // decreased the index value since SelectedRows property loses an object
     }
}
```